# htaccess Block access to directory with two exceptions

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, authentication

I can't figure out how to write an .htaccess file which blocks all access to a directory except for reading html files, which sould be allowed and php-files which require athentication. Denying all access and allowing html works fine but asking for a password for php-files doesn't.

Here is what I came up with:

```
<FilesMatch  ".*\.php$">
        AuthName "Test area"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
        AuthType Basic
        require valid-user
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.html?$">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
</FilesMatch>

order Allow,Deny
Deny from ALL
```

Thanks,

AC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess to pass authentification **or** authorization instead of both, you need a `Satisfy Any` (default is `Satisfy All`)

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<FilesMatch  "\.php$">
    Satisfy Any
    AuthName "Test area"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    require valid-user
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.html?$">
    Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
```

Note: for Apache >= 2.4, this method is deprecated (cf new `<Require(All|None|Any)>` and `Require` directives).